# Tags in posts link to the wrong site

Tags: bug, tags, mso-mse-split

[Remove the [organization] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251485/remove-this-organization) was moved from here to Meta Stack Overflow. It is about a tag on Stack Overflow that should burninated. When I click on the tag, I am taken to this very site, not Stack Overflow. The same doesn't happen in questions asked on Stack Overflow that didn't get migrated, such as [Get rid of move tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251690/get-rid-of-move-tag)

The tag is [organization](/questions/tagged/organization). The tag reference on this very site takes to Stack Overflow, which is still not the expected behavior, since it should point to tags used on [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com), which is the main site for this site. If this doesn't make sense because Stack Exchange doesn't use tags, then `[tag:organization]` should links to tag pages here.

I tried editing the question in question, to see if that would help, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed: The tag reference on Meta Stack Overflow takes to Stack Overflow, while here it takes to this very site.